# XDebug with Android

Tags: php, android, netbeans, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have an android app doing post requests to my local web server running on Wamp.
I would like to break on the PHP code.

I've seen a lot of questions about how to debug code running on a remote server, but in all of them, the IDE (here netbeans) and the browser are on the same computer.

Here I have the following scheme :

[image: Remote browser debugging]

The request works, but impossible to break in Netbeans.
Even with the browser on the same computer, impossible to trigger a breakpoint when the request doesn't come from localhost :

[image]

The request in red works as excepted, but xdebug does not trigger any breakpoint.

I tried to set:

```
- xdebug.remote_autostart=1
or
- xdebug.remote_host=localhost
or
- xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.10
```

My current configuration is :

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I tried to change the remote port but nothing changed.
I also tried to disable my firewall, nothing.
I may misunderstand how xdebug works, so if you have corrections, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more researches, I think the problem was a bad re-routing configuration of my port 9000. My computer is behind a router, and even with the port forwarded to my local ip, I still cannot have xdebug triggered.

I've found [this tutorial](http://stuporglue.org/setting-up-xdebug-with-netbeans-on-windows-with-a-remote-apache-server/) explaining how to configure remote debugging using SSH tunnel. So I installed my website on a remote linux server and have now the following scheme :

[image]

I know it's not an exact solution to my original problem, but the end goal was to trigger xdebug on my computer with a request coming from the tablet, and it works with this configuration.

I hope somebody will find this useful.